# Google Drive admin sdk not returning results

Tags: google-admin-sdk

We just upgraded our google drive account to unlimited. I'm trying to get google drive activity by calling: `https://www.googleapis.com/admin/reports/v1/activity/users/all/applications/drive`

Even though I know there has been upload and download and other activity I always get the following request body response. What am I doing wrong?

```
{
 "kind": "admin#reports#activities",
 "etag": "\"K7weO5KXLrPU3p64O3h2OrP24p0/Vx72S7w5bR8cVoa6z9PWL7D5sM0\""
}
```

**note** I didn't get new credentials after I upgraded the account to unlimited. I assumed my access token still works after the upgrade.

Thanks
Al

Answer (score 0):

I think your URI request is lacking and is too broad so you got an almost empty JSON response. Try this more specific [Reports API requests for Drive](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/manage-audit-drive):

```
//fetch 25 of your accont's Drive events
GET https://www.googleapis.com/admin/reports/v1/activity/users/all
/applications/drive?maxResults=25
```

The following example gets a report on all of a customer's Drive events for the past 180 days. The customerId specifies which customer the report is to be retrieved for.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/admin/reports/v1/activity/users/all
/applications/drive?customerId=ABC123xyz
```

The following example retrieves a report on all changes for an account done by a specific user

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/admin/reports/v1/activity/users/liz@example.com
/applications/drive
```

You can read more of that in the given link.

You can also give this a go in the [Try-it section](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/activities/list#try-it) and fill-in the parameters that apply.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you Noogui, I found out that since we just upgraded to unlimited it took 12 hours for the upgrade to unlimited to take effect. When I tried the same thing this morning I got results back.

Comment: good job, hope the commnds in the answer will be of use as well