# No items returned when querying Admin Report API for user activity

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-apis-explorer

I am a GSuite admin, and I'm attempting to use the Admin Report API to query for a list of Google Drive activity in my org:

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/activities/list

However, when I try this API using the in-browser "Try this API" sidebar, I get a 200 response that doesn't contain any items:

```
{
 "kind": "admin#reports#activities",
 "etag": "\"S3VtFupSeWkpIL4X4oyC3FQHUIg/yjNPMzJe-48yhglJqAJOjeVcbcs\""
}
```

Why isn't there a list of activities?

Comment: There's a related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39377882/google-drive-admin-sdk-not-returning-results) which solved with this same issue of not returning any results. You will need to be more specific to your query of the API calls.

Answer (score 1):

Mystery solved, looks like this API is only available for the G Suite Business tier, but I'm on the Basic tier.